# Is it safe to truncate the catalog_category_product table?

Tags: mysql, catalog, indexing

I was trying to reindex Category Products and I kept getting "There was a problem with reindexing process" error message. When I into SSH and tried 'php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product', I got:

Category Products index process unknown error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails
>   (`account_mage142`.`mg_catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_MG_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_MG_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`category_id`) REFERENCES `mg_catalog_category_entity`)' in
>   /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

and

> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>
> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`account_mage142`.`mg_catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_MG_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_MG_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`category_id`) REFERENCES `mg_catalog_category_entity`), query was:
>   INSERT INTO `mg_catalog_category_product_index` (`category_id`,
>   `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`)
>   SELECT `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`category_id`,
>   `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`product_id`,
>   `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`position`,
>   `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`is_parent`,
>   `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`store_id`,
>   `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`visibility` FROM
>   `mg_catalog_category_product_index_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` =
>   VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`), `is_parent` =
>   VALUES(`is_parent`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `visibility` =
>   VALUES(`visibility`)' in
>   /home/account/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235

I was advised to truncate the mg_catalog_category_product table but I was wondering if it is safe to do so.. will  removing the data in this table have any adverse effects to the data in the Magento store?

Answer (score 4):

It took some digging, but I eventually found this article. Problem solved. :)
http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=70

**EDIT:**

Mark as answered, details from link below for future reference:

> This error occurs when trying to run the Category Products index, and
>   is due to the indexing process attempting to insert a row into the
>   catalog_category_product_index table, where either the product_id or
>   the category_id don't exist. This causes the "Intergrity Constraint
>   Violation".
>
> This can sometimes happen when a database gets corrupt, often from 3rd
>   party desktop type software or a badly written extension.
>
> To fix this, first check that this is indeed the issue. Backup your
>   database and then run the following SQL to see if any product and/or
>   category associations are incorrect:
>
> ```
> # Determine incorrect product associations
> SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE
> product_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
>
> # Determine incorrect categories
> SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE 
> category_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_category_entity);
> ```
>
> If that returns a record, you'll know exactly which product is in a
>   non-existent category or which category has a non-existent product.
>   Run the following SQL to then remove those invalid records:
>
> ```
> # Delete incorrect product associations
> DELETE FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE 
> product_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
>
> # Delete incorrect categories
> DELETE FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE 
> category_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_category_entity);
> ```
>
> Now log back into Magento Admin and reindex the Category Products
>   index.

Comment: please donot a comment as answer.Please describe or put comment

Answer (score 2):

In word, it is not safe to truncate the table

In magento, `products  and there categories relation` has been saved at table `catalog_category_product` .`catalog_category_product` is the main table for mapped between them.

If you delete the record from this table then the `relation between product and category will be lost.`

So,please donot truncate the records.

### [Edit]

**You can may be resolved the issue by delete the those records:**

1. `product ids` which does not exit in `catalog_product_entity`(main
   product table).

**Query:**

`DELETE FROM catalog_category_product WHERE 
product_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity)`

2. `category ids` which does `not exit` in `catalog_cateory_entity`(main
       category table).

**Query:**

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE 
category_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_category_entity)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, I found that that was not helpful at all!

Comment: It is not my hand:)

Answer (score 2):

> **DO NOT TRUNCATE THE TABLE `catalog_category_product` TABLE. It is the table that binds your product with different categories.**

Your error gives the hint that, Magento is trying to insert a new row in the table `mg_catalog_category_product_index` which has a `category_id` value that is not present in `mg_catalog_category_entity`.

Now `catalog_category_entity` table will have an entry corresponds to every categories in your site. So a category id which is not present in this table is an "unknown" entity as far as Magento concerned. Magento enforces this by defining a foreign key in `catalog_category_product_index` table.

Errors like this very hard to debug. I am now quiet busy. If I find some fair time, I will update this answer and will try to help you.