# Magento2 error while updating product URL keys

Tags: magento2, import

Getting this error while importing produdct for updating product URLs

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`catalog_category_product`, CONSTRAINT
>   `CAT_CTGR_PRD_CTGR_ID_SEQUENCE_CAT_CTGR_SEQUENCE_VAL` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`category_id`) REFERENCES `sequence_catalog_category` (`sequenc),
>   query was: INSERT INTO`catalog_category_product
>   `(`product_id`,`category_id`,`position`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?,
>   ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`product_id`= VALUES(`product_id`),`
>   category_id`= VALUES(`category_id`)

Comment: I got the solution from this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72549/is-it-safe-to-truncate-the-catalog-category-product-table  and it did work for me